# insert button, scripting with c# in unity not appear

Tags: c#, button, user-interface, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am already typing this code in MonoDevelop, and drag it to the main camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    void onGUI() {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f, 200, 50), "Click ME!");
    }
}
```

but the button still does not appear. What did I miss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put controls on screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699761/how-do-i-put-controls-on-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The method name is case sensitive and, in this case, needs to be `OnGUI` not `onGUI` (as per [the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html)).