# Unity Engine C#: Buttons Do Nothing

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue where my Unity GUI.Buttons aren't running the code when they are clicked in this script (they work in a similar fashion in another script) and I was wondering why. I can tell that nothing is happening as not even the sound plays, let alone the scene transitioning.

To give a bit of background, I want to have a timer which will stop and show the time it took the player to finish the level though that bit seems fine. Then they can decide what to do next with the 3 buttons: next level, menu or quit.

Here is the entire Unity C# Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class finishScript : MonoBehaviour {

public GUISkin skin;

public bool finished = false;

private float timer = 0.0f;

AudioSource a;
public AudioClip clickSound;

void Start ()
{
    a = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (!finished) { timer += Time.deltaTime; } 
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.skin = skin;

    if (!finished)
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(2, 2, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 16), "Time: " + Mathf.Round(timer).ToString());
    }

    if (finished)
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width/4, Screen.height/4, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/4), 
            "Congratulations!\n\nYou finished the level in:\n" + Mathf.Round(timer).ToString());

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4, Screen.height/2, Screen.width/8, Screen.height/8), "Main Manu"))
        {
            a.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 3f);
            SceneManager.LoadScene("main_menu");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(3*Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 2, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 8), "Next Level"))
        {
            a.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 3f);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect( 3 * Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 2, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 8), "Quit"))
        {
            a.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 3f);
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

So I just want to know what is specifically wrong with this and why, thanks!

Comment: You CAN NOT use the old very gui system in Unity now.  Simply use the ordinary UI system.  It just could not be easier. (1) click "add canvas"  (2) click "add button". You're done.  Simply **drag any functions** you want run by the button to the button Inspector.  It literally couldn't be easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put controls on screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699761/how-do-i-put-controls-on-screen)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That does look a lot easier. However, I know that this method does actually work to some extent as it has in my previous scenes (same project) so whilst I will do they way you've suggested, it still leaves the question of what I've done wrong open.

Comment: hi Matthew, I'm sorry you ***can not use*** the "very old" "gui" system. Are you using Unity5?  Don't know how clear I can be.  Click "add canvas" click "add button" -you're done!  Ciao!

Comment: Tip - when you click "Add Canvas" just choose "scale with screen size" - it's even easier to use then.  Enjoy

Comment: Yeah I'm using Unity 5 and as I say, I will use the method you have suggested but I still don't understand why it won't work as it does actually work in a different scene in my project so I was just after an explanation. And thank you for your answer I didn't even know that existed!

Comment: hi Matthew, Unity is amazing, well it costs $5000 a year for the pro version so we expect it to be good :/  But the documentation is ***really horrible***.  There are many things they "just don't mention".  Anyway pls enjoy and hopefully lots more questions from you on here!  I suggest you click the "Unity3D" tag (on your right) .. it is very interesting to read previous recent QA.

Comment: I agree with @JoeBlow : There is nothing to be gained by sticking to the old onGUI approach. I think Unity should just deprecate it (hope they do soon). The UI system now is easy- you're able to see what you're making on screen, it uses less CPU, and you can do everything that you could with the old and more.

Comment: Ok thanks guys! I'll get started on remaking it now!

Comment: Hi @andeart, you raise an interesting point. I **spectacularly agree with you** that Unity should now REMOVE the "ancient gui" (it's now like 5 yrs old for goodness sake). YOU ARE RIGHT.

Comment: Dear @andeart if you see this message, please click to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699761/how-do-i-put-controls-on-screen and reload, I edited the answer just for you :)  It saves you typing .. copy and paste.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think you meant to alert OP about that link, not me :P

Comment: @andeart beg your pardon...!! thx

Comment: dear @MatthewBolitho if you see this message, please click to stackoverflow.com/questions/34699761/… and reload, I edited the answer just for you :) It saves you typing .. copy and paste :)